# Return value of this Fibonacci Number (python)

Tags: python, function, scope, return, fibonacci

In book example, I have this function for Fibonacci Number. I don't understand why it doesn't give any Fibonacci Number in return when I invoke function by `fib(3)`

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n an int >= 0
    Returns Fibonacci of n"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
 fib(3)
```

But with following code, when I invoke testFib by testFib(3), it did return the string 'fib of i = fib(i)'. fib(i) is value in the print. Can anyone help me understand what is the difference between these two fib(3) callout (one is my direct `fib(3)` callout, the other is inside of testFib,`print('fib of', i, '=',fib(i))`

```
def testFib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print ('fib of', i, '=', fib(i))

testFib(3)
```

I just learned the essence of Scope Nest for python program recently. I have a feeling this may be a good example to get a better understand of the concept.

Comment: Are you running this in an interpreter shell? You need to **print** the return value, or else you won't see anything if you just do `python my_fib_script.py`

Comment: ...Okay... I thought I tried `print(fib(3))` and it didn't work. But this time it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

def fib(n):
"""Assumes n an int >= 0
Returns Fibonacci of n"""
if n == 0 or n == 1:
return 1
else:
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
fib(3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33499318)